# How to add infinite components when a button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a social media WinForm. I have a function that basically makes a new picture box when a button is clicked

```
Public Sub NewPost()
    picture as new picturebox
    picture.Width = 208
    picture.Height = 264
    picture.Image = Form2.PictureBox1.Image
    picture.Location = New Point(258, 60)
End Sub
```

The thing is it only generates 1 new picture box because I have to make a new variable each time I want to add a picturebox, and eachtime I have to have a new name. I know my question Is a bit confusing but help would be nice thanks

Comment: `PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();` Your location is always the same.  You need to add the PictureBox to a Container's Control collection.    Consider a FlowLayoutPanel as the container..  You can't get "infinite".  You will run out resources.

Comment: @LarsTech C#? Could confuse a new user.

Comment: @Mary it is ok I am familiar with c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trap events for your dynamic PictureBoxes, then you'll have to abandon the `WithEvents` model and move to using [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement).

Here's a quick example where the name of the PictureBox is displayed when it is clicked.  Note that I am not setting a `Location` since they are being added to a FlowLayoutPanel which takes care of the placement for you:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        NewPost()
    End Sub

    Public Sub NewPost()
        Dim picture As New PictureBox
        picture.Width = 208
        picture.Height = 264
        picture.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        ' ...etc...

        Dim index As Integer = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count + 1
        picture.Name = "pb" & index

        AddHandler picture.Click, AddressOf picture_Click

        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture)
    End Sub

    Private Sub picture_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        Debug.Print(pb.Name)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks just used it never heard of FlowLayoutPanels!

Comment: @Khaled. Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This will help future readers and earn a few reps for your.

Comment: And if I wanted to connect an imagelist how would I do that.

Comment: That's a pretty vague question..."connect" an ImageList how?...to what?

Comment: Sorry, I have an imagelist, is there to make the `FlowLayoutPanel`'s images, the `ImageLists` images. If the question is still vague I will send a picture

Comment: Sure...you access the ImageList just like an array.  Assuming you already have it loaded with images, you could simply use the Controls.Count property of the FlowLayout panel to know which number to use from the ImageList.  Maybe something like: `picture.Image = ImageList1.Images(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count)`

Comment: Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

> because I have to make a new variable each time

Not necessarily.  You just want to keep a *reference* to the object.  That reference doesn't need to be its own variable, it can just as easily be an element in a list.  For example, suppose on your form you have a list of `PictureBox` objects as a class-level member:

```
Dim pictureBoxes As New List(Of PictureBox)()
```

Then in your method you can just add to that list:

```
Public Sub NewPost()
    Dim pictureBox As New PictureBox
    pictureBox.Width = 208
    pictureBox.Height = 264
    pictureBox.Image = Form2.PictureBox1.Image
    pictureBox.Location = New Point(258, 60)
    Me.pictureBoxes.Add(pictureBox)
End Sub
```

In this case the `pictureBox` variable is local to the `NewPost` method and gets re-created each time.  But `pictureBoxes` is a class-level member and keeps track of the growing list of `PictureBox` objects that you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for while loop to create n number of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing ControlCollection

```
Public Function NewPost() As String
    Dim picture As New PictureBox
    'your code
    picture.Name = "Pb" & Form2.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).Count
    Form2.Controls.Add(picture)
    Return picture.Name
End Function
```

then you can retrive it

```
    DirectCast(Form2.Controls(NewPost), PictureBox).Image = Form2.PictureBox1.Image
    'OR
    DirectCast(Form2.Controls("Pb12"), PictureBox).Image = Form2.PictureBox1.Image
```